# Django view based cache with authed users

Tags: python, django, caching

So I am using view based cache in django as I have some views that are not really suitable for caching and others that really are. However, in some of these views that I cache the output will be different for different users. Is there a way to have a view based cache separate for different users? The @vary_on_cookie decorator looked like exactly what I needed but it doesn't seem to work for view based cache's?

At the moment around my view I have:

```
@vary_on_cookie
@cache_page(60 * 5)
def view(request):
```

If you log in as anonmymous you can see what was cache's by a logged in user.

Any ideas? I know I could probably use the low level cache for this type of problem but I'm surprised if there wasn't an easier django way of doing it, seems like it would be a common problem.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use client-based caching with `cache_control`.  Like:

```
@cache_control(max_age=60 * 5)
def view(request):
```

Comment: So with this it only cache's a page if the user has been on it before? So if two users who are both not authed will both try to access the view it won't go through the cache? As in they will both process the view separately?

Comment: Anyway to do it with cache all anonymous publicly and cache authed user privately? Looks like patch_cache_control(response, public=True) might be what I need, I'm going to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [snippet here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1493/) that uses the Django cache framework. I think you can modify it for yourself. There's line 38:

```
key = make_cache_key(request.get_full_path(), getattr(request, 'supports_html5', None))
```

You can change it to

```
key = make_cache_key(request.user[.id], request.get_full_path(), getattr(request, 'supports_html5', None))
```

So that users have different page keys.